# Standardized format for specification for data quality tests

Tags: specifications, data-quality

I'm working on automation of data quality tests. I found a [Great-expectation framework](https://greatexpectations.io/) that seems wonderful to do the tests. But using it requires "manual" coding of the checks & keep them up-to-date with changes in the spec (requiring a coder work).

I'd find it much more effective & efficient if there is some format in which requirements on data quality would be embedded directly in the specification. Then some relatively simple script would "translate" the spec to the executable code using the library.

Our db spec (it is a L2 in DWH, so it matches the format of output csv) is primarilly in the Excel format.

Is there any standardized format to be used?

Thanks a lot for any advice.